# Block screen orientation to Portrait for Phone and allow both orientation for tablets

Tags: android, tabs, screen-orientation

I tried the following code in `onCreate` to set screen `orientation` to `Portrait` in Phones and allow both `orientations` in `Tablets`.

```
if (resources.configuration.screenWidthDp < (resources.getDimension(R.dimen.max_phone_screen_width) /
                    resources.displayMetrics.density)) {
       requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
}
```

The problem with this code is, if the app is launched in Landscape mode in the phone, the app is first launched in Landscape and then shifts to portrait. How to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the activity element in manifest to initialize the activity with portrait mode.
Then in onCreate

```
if (resources.configuration.screenWidthDp >= (resources.getDimension(R.dimen.max_phone_screen_width) /
                resources.displayMetrics.density)
    ) {
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
```

Comment: This does not fix my issue. If I add so, when opening the app in landscape mode in Tablet, it will launch in Portrait mode first and then shift to Landscape

Comment: As I understand, You want it SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT in phone and UNSPECIFIC in tablet?

Comment: Yes. No proper solutions available for this